# Not enough values while compiling procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, collections, package, nested-table

Im trying to get the compile the below program and im getting not enough values error. This program will give the first 5 maximum and mininum salary holding by employees.

```
select * from all_tables where table_name like 'EMP5%';

create or replace package ptest1 is
Type rec is record (emin number,salmin number,min_salary number,emax number,salmax number,max_salary number);
TYPE T71 is table of rec;
procedure min_max(inp number, oup out T71);
end;
/

create or replace package body ptest1 as
procedure min_max(inp number, oup out T71)
as
begin
select emin,salmin,min_salary,emax,salmax,max_salary
into oup
from 
(select * from 
(select empno emin,sal salmin,row_number() over(order by sal asc) min_salary from emp5 where sal is not null) where min_salary <= inp ) t1,
(select * from 
(select empno emax,sal salmax,row_number() over(order by sal desc) max_salary from emp5 where sal is not null) where max_salary <= inp) t2
where t1.min_salary = t2.max_salary;
for i in oup.first..oup.last
loop
dbms_output.put_line('Employee number  '||oup(i).emin);
end loop;
end;
end ptest1;
/
```

Comment: Assuming you missed out the `bulk collect` line when posting, this compiles and runs; so not sure why you have a problem - possibly you've retyped the whoel thing and accidentally fixed it? I'm not sure the logic does what you want though. You need a filter to restrict to five rows for a start; but why the subqueries and joins; and why use PL/SQL at all?

Comment: I need to display top 5(based on the input either it will be 5 or other number) min and max salary for the employees. I need to print it using bulk collect

Comment: OK, I see how you're using the `imp` now. So this does what you want, I think - except you're only printing `emin`, not `emin` and `emax`. It doesn't throw a not-enough-values error anyway, but I have no idea what is different in the code you are actually running.

Comment: if possible, could you please create a procedure with out parameter as collection(nested type) which will return top n max and min salary for the employee. n is the input for the procedure

Comment: I still don't understand. That is what your procedure already does.

Comment: No....Its throwing not enough value error